# aload_2 seems to be pointing to the first argument

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, synchronized

I'm using `javap` to disassemble some java bytecode because, after having decompiled it using jd-gui, I was getting some errors with a method. However, comparing the disassembled bytecode with what jd-gui gave me, it looks like aload_2 is pointing to the first argument, rather than aload_1.

The method in question is a public, non-static, void, likely synchronized method. (I believe the fact that the method is likely synchronized is why jd-gui had some trouble with it..) Anyway, the method takes 6 arguments (int, long, String, String, String, String) and those variables were given the following names by jd-gui:

```
int paramInt, long paramLong, String paramString1, String paramString2, String paramString3, String paramString4
```

Now, to show you what I mean when I say the first argument seems to be aload_2, let me post part of the disassembled and decompiled code.

**Decompiled:**

```
Object localObject1;
if (paramString2.equals("DELETE"))
{
    localObject1 = new HttpDelete(paramString1);
}
```

**Disassembled:**

```
11: aload         5
13: ldc           #214                // String DELETE
15: invokevirtual #219                // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
18: ifeq          192
21: new           #221                // class org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpDelete
24: dup           
25: aload         4
27: invokespecial #223                // Method org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpDelete."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
30: astore        8
```

In the disassembled code, lines 11 through 18 are the same as the line `if(paramString2.equals("DELETE"))` in the decompiled code. Notice how aload 5 points to the 4rd argument (paramString2). This is not what I would expect. Normally aload_0 = this, aload_1 = the first argument, aload_2 = the second argument, and so on.

**You would expect aload 5 to point to the 5th argument, but jd-gui interprets it as pointing to the 4th argument. Why? Does the fact that the method is likely synchronized have anything to do with this?**

For any clarification that may be needed, I would have interpreted the disassembled bytecode as this:

```
if(paramString3.equals("DELETE"))
{
    HttpDelete httpDelete = new HttpDelete(paramString2);
    //More code on down here...
}
```

Comment: The numbering of arguments is just a convention. Can you post more of the byte code?

Comment: Here is the entire method: http://pastebin.com/KiWG5VHX

Comment: Likely synchronized? Either it is synchronized or it's not. Also, for future reference, Krakatau can usually decompile code where other decompilers like jd-gui fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `long` argument will take up a pair of local variables [JVMS 2.6.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.1).

Comment: Much better, and explains what's going on very well. +1.